# Botframework Composer Custom Action not registered in factory

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

I have an existing bot. I have added a custom action as described [in the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions?tabs=csharp).
When the bot is started, only the errormessage:

```
mybot.dialog error: Type Mycustomaction not registered in factory.
```

is displayed in the chat window.

Initially the bot was created with Composer 1.x After migrating to Composer 2.x the existing custom actions did not work and adding new custom actions fails.

Comment: did you convert your bot to use the new runtime? Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-migrate-bot-to-2-0#migrate-your-custom-actions and see if you missed out on any step.

Comment: Yes the bot was converted. There is no helpful information in the "Migrate your custom actions" section.

Answer (score 2):

It can also occur if you are stupid like me and just copy the `BotComponent` class from some other component and forget to update it to register the new one :D

```
public class MyDialogBotComponent : BotComponent
{
   public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      services.AddSingleton<DeclarativeType>(sp => new DeclarativeType<MyDialog>(MyDialog.Kind));
   }
}
```

Or if your

```
[JsonProperty("$kind")] public const string Kind = nameof(MyDialog);
```

Is not updated to the new component

Comment: That was my issue, thanx for reminding me :D

Answer (score 1):

This error comes if you haven't added the new custom action in the appsettings.json file of the bot under components

> mybot.dialog error: Type Mycustomaction not registered in factory.

```
"components": [
  {
    "name": "FirstCustomAction"
  },
  {
    "name": "SecondCustomAction"
  }
],
```